wordpress preview add size
The wordpress preview has “desktop”, “tablet” and “mobile” by default.
I want to add my own angle of view to it and preview.
Which page can I change to add the angle of view?
I would appreciate it if you could tell me. Thank you in advance.

Use inspect tool for your browser and toggle device toolbar from where you can select predefined devices , resolutions etc or custom. You can also add your own devices too.

Thank you for your comment.
I would like to check the display on the edit screen.
